# Laravel validation required and not a specific value

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel validation set up
I am trying to make sure that
A. the field is required based off another field's value
B. That this current fields value is not ___

This is what I have now

```
  'israelOptionCollege' => 'required_if:israelOption,"Yes"|not_in: "- Please select an option -"',
```

Even if israelOption == No
when this fields is returning : - Please select an option -"
it's marking the field as invalid.

Comment: why would something have the value of "- Please select an option -"?

Comment: That is the default, because I need a blank box for other. It's very convoluted code I need to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the quotations around "Yes".

You may also try using this syntax:

```
required_if:israelOption,==,Yes
```